# After configure the nginx, I can't see the index page

Tags: python, nginx, tornado

This is my first time to use nginx

I wrote a simple python/tornado code as the following, when I used `python server.py` I could see the index.html page.

```
from tornado.options import define, options
from db import MongoImpl

define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.render("./pages/index.html")

app = tornado.web.Application([(r'/', IndexHandler)],
                            debug=True)
app.listen(options.port)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Then I started to configure the nginx.conf, I added the following to default nginx.conf:

```
http {
        server{
                listen 8000;
                root /home/ubuntu/work/mytornado/pages;
                index index.html index.htm;
        }
```

then i `nginx -s reload`

however, when I used `http://myipaddress`, i only see the nginx welcome page, not my index html....

Is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run both nginx and your tornado server on port 8000. You need to give them each a different port, and configure nginx to proxy to tornado with a `proxy_pass` directive (this will replace the `root` directive you have here which serves pages from the filesystem. If you want nginx to serve some files from the filesystem and some from tornado then you'll need to use two `location` blocks).

A complete nginx configuration for use with tornado can be found in the docs: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html#running-behind-a-load-balancer